# When to use async versions of JsonSerializer (SerializeAsync/DeserializeAsync)?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, serialization, json.net

Serializers like `JsonSerializer` has async version of methods.

I want to clarify in what situations to use them?

I usually use simple versions Serialize/Deserialize by default and never care about async versions. But probably it's preferable to use async versions in some cases.

Comment: Like all async cases, when you don't want to block the current thread waiting for IO operations to complete. When reading from a network stream or request body for example, the synchronous methods will block while they wait for the server to send data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevant questions here are:

1. Do I already have the data in-process, or is the data coming in *asynchronously*, for example over a socket?
2. Do I *care* about the overhead of blocking IO operations?

If the data is already in a `string`, `byte[]`, `MemoryStream`, or anything similar: then just use synchronous deserialize (etc); it'll be *faster* (the async machinery itself has overheads). If the data is streaming in from (or out to) an external source: consider async.

The second question can roughly be approximated to "Am I running on a server?"; client and console applications: *usually* aren't going to suffer massively from an idle thread (if we ignore UI blocking, which can be avoided in other ways), where-as on server applications: idle threads (blocked on pending IO) can severely limit throughput. Servers inherently run at much higher concurrency, and threads are a limited and expensive resource.

Answer (score 0):

Of course they must be used when you want to perform JSON serialization or deserialization operations **asynchronously**.

The async versions of `JsonSerializer` methods are particularly useful when dealing with **large** JSON payloads **or** when performing I/O-bound operations, such as reading from or writing to a file or a network stream.

So by using them you can avoid blocking the main/UI thread and allow other operations to continue while the JSON data is being processed. This can lead to improving the responsiveness(UX) and scalability of your application.